# How could I replace a form with text when form is submitted?

Tags: php, email, forms, replace, submit

I want my form to disappear when someone submits it (and it passes all of the error checking)
and text replaces where it was and says something like "Thank you a confirmation email has been sent"

What are some ways I would be able to do this?

I have the form working and the error checks and everything working, all I would need to do is make it disappear when the user clicks submit..

I am using php, Thanks!

Comment: Are you submitting the form with AJAX or standard form submit?

Comment: Use **element**.style.display to make the form elements invisible. Probably the simplest way. If you want to stay on the same page, make sure you use AJAX to activate your PHP code. Also, make sure your button isn't of type "submit". It should be "button", or it would submit and you would lose the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
var td = document.forms.contact.parentNode
if (td.innerHTML) {
    td.innerHTML = "your message"
} else {
    td.textContent = "your message"
}
```

If you are submitting using AJAX, put it at the end
If you are using basic forms, put it as a function in the onSubmit attribute of your form

Example:

```
<form onSubmit="emptyForm();"
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use some Javascript to :
1.) submit the form via AJAX,
2.) change the content of the element holding the form

```
<div id='myForm_container'>
    <form id='myForm'>
         <input id="name" name="name">
         <input id="email" name="email">
        <input type=submit id='mySubmit'>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    $('#mySubmit').click(function(){
        //do your validation and if passes:
        $.post("form_submit.php", { name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val()},
        function(data){
            $('#myForm_container').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: in this case you would have the form_submit.php return the HTML you are wanting to replace the form with.

Answer (score 0):

I did NOT test the form on http://www.sligroup.ca/contact_us.php because i do not want to sendthem a pointless message.

All you have to do wrap up the part of you script that outputs the forms html source in an pif block an check if the orm was already submitted correctly. No javascript needed.

Simple example:

```
$validFormSubmitted = validateform();
...
if(!$validFormSubmitted){
echo $formText;
}
```

[EDIT: this will reload the page without the form. You said you want a PHP solution but if you do not want to reload the page you will have to use AJAX]

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean... What is $formText ?

Comment: $formText is where you should put the html for your form.